# Inserting multiple rows into matrix, shifting existing rows

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

### Question:

I'm looking for the most efficient way to insert multiple rows `R` into a matrix `M` before specified rows `I`, while shifting existing rows down.

### Example:

```
M = [1 1 1 1;
     2 2 2 2;
     3 3 3 3;
     4 4 4 4;
     5 5 5 5];
I = [1 3 3 5];
R = [-6 -6 -6 -6;
     -7 -7 -7 -7;
     -8 -8 -8 -8
     -9 -9 -9 -9];
```

The result should be the matrix:

```
[-6 -6 -6 -6
  1  1  1  1
  2  2  2  2
 -7 -7 -7 -7
 -8 -8 -8 -8
  3  3  3  3
  4  4  4  4
 -9 -9 -9 -9
  5  5  5  5]
```

Comment: I am not really sure what I is supposed to do since it only seems as you have stacked `R` on `M`, but for that you can try `mtx = [M;R]` or `mtx = vertcat(M,R)`

Comment: @patrik that's not what the OP wants. He wants to insert rows of R into M at positions given by I. It's not a simple concatenation.

Comment: @am304 I see, and to OP, sorry, of course it is not what you was looking for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This functionality is available on the [file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9984-insertrows--v2-0--may-2008-). What it essentially does is:

```
ind = [1:size(M, 1) I-1];
[~, ind] = sort(ind);
MR = [M; R];
MR = MR(ind,:);
```

Comment: Wow, that is a very nice way of doing it!

Answer (score 2):

The following will work, but I think only if the indices in `I` are sorted in increasing order (if not, you can always add some sorting steps first). In any case, I would test it with "real" data:

```
[m,n] = size(M);     
l = length(I);
MM = zeros(m+l,n);

MM(I+(1:l)-1,:) = R; % I+(1:l)-1 are the row indices of the final matrix in which to insert the the rows of R 
MM(~ismember(1:(l+m),I+(1:l)-1),:) = M; % ~ismember(...) are the other row indices (using logical indexing)
```

This gives:

```
>> MM
MM =

  -6  -6  -6  -6
   1   1   1   1
   2   2   2   2
  -7  -7  -7  -7
  -8  -8  -8  -8
   3   3   3   3
   4   4   4   4
  -9  -9  -9  -9
   5   5   5   5
```

Comment: Ah, good idea. Didn't know about the `ismember` function. I understand this is equivalent to `sparse(I+(0:l-1),1,true,m+l,1)`; maybe that could even speed things up.

Answer (score 2):

This could be one approach -

```
R_rowind = cumsum([I(1) diff(I)+1]) %// Row indices where rows from R are
                                    %// to be inserted in the output matrix
rowidx_arr = 1:size(M,1)+size(R,1)  %// array of [1 : number_of_rows_in_output]
out(setdiff(rowidx_arr,R_rowind),:) = M %// Insert rows from M into output array
out(R_rowind,:) = R %// Insert rows from R into output array
```

Please note that for *inserting rows from M into output array*, you can this `bsxfun` based alternative approach as well -

```
out(all(bsxfun(@ne,rowidx_arr,R_rowind'),1),:) =  M
```

Comment: Also good idea, it seems similar to @am304 s approach, but without logical indexing. So I guess this would also require `I` to be sorted. I guess the `bsxfun` will be fast for small number of insertions.